# why the buttons are not stable

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout

why the buttons are not stable

As can be seen from the pictures below, why are the buttons in different places in other phones

can you help me with this

I want the buttons to be in the same place on every phone. (like the first picture)

My phone

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5A6j.jpg)

my friends phone (huwai)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aUo3.jpg)

My friends phone (samsung)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coBlb.jpg)

The codes I use are below. How do I make changes to these codes will fix this problem? I don't know much about coding

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@drawable/v"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/y"
        android:text="Değiştir"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:onClick="random"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/y"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:text="Kopyala"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:onClick="kopyala"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <Button
        android:text="Paylaş"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/y"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="140dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="paylas"/>

    
    
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use constraint layout instead of relative layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/cardview_shadow_start_color"
            android:text="Değiştir"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:onClick="random"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/cardview_shadow_start_color"
            android:text="Kopyala"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:onClick="kopyala"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"/>

        <Button
            android:text="Paylaş"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/cardview_shadow_start_color"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:onClick="paylas"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Change your layout with this and then check.

Comment: I guess this solved my problem. My friends are sleeping. I'll try them later, too. I tried it on another phone and my problem was fixed. thanks my friend

Comment: please consider _explaining_ your solution instead of just saying `try this`, if you explain what you did, at least people learn something

Comment: Use layout weight for those three button to get exact size of buttons and make the buttons width match_parent and text size should be in 'sp' like '15sp' instead of '15dp'.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding weights in linear layout with horizontal orientation (puts views next to each other)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button 1"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="15dp" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button 2"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button 3"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="15dp" />


        </LinearLayout>
        
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@drawable/v"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="3">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/y"
    android:text="Değiştir"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:onClick="random"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/y"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:text="Kopyala"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:onClick="kopyala"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

<Button
    android:text="Paylaş"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/y"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="140dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:onClick="paylas"/>



 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please consider _explaining_ your solution instead of just saying `try this`, if you explain what you did, at least people learn something

Comment: Use layout weight for those three button to get exact size of buttons and make the buttons width match_parent and text size should be in 'sp' like '15sp' instead of '15dp'.

Answer (score 0):

This is because different screens have different screen sizes and pixel density.
So it shows up as different in different devices.

A few things that you can do is.
Gives the start end margins and then constrain the layout so that it looks the same in different phones.
Instead of wrap content use defined length and width to set the picture of how you want it.

Have different versions of images in (mdpi,xxdpi etc) your drawable .

Use
implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.5'.
This library helps to scale according to the parameters of the phone you're running it on.